# String Replace doesn't replace double back slashes in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

Maybe I am missing something here

I have a variable `dir` coming in looking something like `\\\\SERVERNAME\\dir\\subdir`

I need it to look like `\\SERVERNAME\dir\subdir`

I used string.Replace routine but it did not replace the double slashes, the problem is that when i try to use the path as is, it doesn't find the file.

How would I use string.Replace here in order to get a valid path?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just how the debugger is showing it to you? It does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# the backslash character, "\", is used to escape characters in strings.  For example, in the string "Hello\nworld", the "\n" represents a newline character.  So, in general, when C# sees a "\" in a string it expects to treat it as part of a special command character, rather than as a literal "\".

So, how do you tell C# that you want a literal backslash to appear in your string, that it isn't part of a special command character?  You escape the backslash.  And the escape character is also a backslash.  So to tell C# that you really want a literal "\" to appear in your string (eg in a file path) you use two backslashes: "`\\`".

Say I wanted to set a variable to the following path: C:\Temp\FileDrop

In C# I'd have to do the following:

```
string myPath = "C:\\Temp\\FileDrop";
```

I suspect that when you see the value of a variable looking like `\\\\SERVERNAME\\dir\\subdir` it is escaping the backslash characters so the real value of the variable is `\\SERVERNAME\dir\subdir`.

By the way, if you're copying and pasting long paths from, say, Windows Explorer, it can be a real pain to have to double up the backslashes to escape them.  So C# has a special string literal character, "@".  If you prefix a string with a "@" then it will treat the string exactly as written.  eg

```
string myPath = @"C:\Temp\FileDrop";
```

Comment: thanks! youe answer did it. I was concatenating it and some parts had it as is and some had it escaped with @.

Comment: Glad to know the answer was useful.

Answer (score 2):

`dir.Replace(@"\\", @"\")` should do the trick.